# Check DataSet Details View Textbox Value On Form Load

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a winform with a Dataset that loads/shows a record from the database upon form load using Details view with textboxes instead of DataGridView.  What i'm trying to do is look at the value of one of these textboxes when the form loads, and execute some code based on what that text is but i cannot figure out where i need to place my if statement that looks at this textbox value.

For instance...

```
if (textbox1.Text == "A")
{
   label1.visible = true;
}
else if (textbox1.Text == "B")
{
   label1.visible = false;
}
```

I have tried putting this code in the formLoad event, in the BindingSource_bindingcomplete event and in the TextChanged event of textbox1 but none of this works upon form load.  I know the if statement works because if i change the text after the form loads to either A or B the label's visible property changes accordingly, it just doesn't look at the original value being loaded and execute this code.

Is it even possible to check a value of a textbox that is being populated from a datasource on form load AND change the properties of something else on the form based on that textbox value at the same time?  Or am i approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: You should use datasource data from this, not user controls since on form load all controlls values are empty.

Comment: Move it to the `Shown` event?